# Merge [usb-drive] and [pendrive]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

Please merge [usb-drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/usb-drive) and [pendrive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pendrive). Both tags describe USB storage.

Pendrive: 40 questions, tag excerpt:

> Storage drives connected by USB devices known otherwise as flash drive, USB stick, USB key and thumb drive. Also includes larger storage devices such as portable hard drives.

USB drive: 403 questions, tag excerpt:

> Storage drives connected by USB devices known otherwise as flash drive, memory stick, pen drive, USB stick, USB key and thumb drive. Also includes larger storage devices such as portable hard drives.

Pretty much exactly the same, they even refer to eachother as synonyms in the excerpt.

Comment: I would question if either tag was actually useful. If there are libraries for dealing with USBs in languages they should be tagged along the lines of "[*language*-usb]". I don't see the use in a general USB drive tag for programming. On the metric of "Can someone be an expert in this tag", I don't think someone could be an expert in every possible USB drive programming implementation.